# RewriteRule syntax in .htaccess won't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/locations/$ location.php
```

The folder "mydomain.com/locations/" does not exist but the locations.php does.
According to the hoster the module mode_rewrite is enabled on the server by default but still my rewrite rule won't work.
The request "mydomain.com/locations/" answers with 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule uses a relative path starting without a leading slash on htaccess context . So remove the slash

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^locations/$ location.php
```